# Zabbix Pre-shared key encryption

Tags: encryption, zabbix

I'm trying to use psk encryption on agent with active checks on Windows 7, but wont work, don't know why.

Here's my agent conf :

```
TLSPSKFile=C:\zabbix\zabbix.txt
TLSPSKIdentity=psk001
TLSConnect=psk
```

When i remove psk option from config file works fine ...

Here is agent log:

```
4008:20160817:100235.765 using configuration file: C:\zabbix\zabbix_agentd.win.conf
4008:20160817:100235.766 agent #0 started [main process]
4820:20160817:100235.766 agent #1 started [collector]
5060:20160817:100235.766 agent #2 started [active checks #1]
5060:20160817:100235.769 no active checks on server [10.29.0.40:10051]: connection of type "unencrypted" is not allowed for host "IDX-INVENTORY"
4520:20160817:100251.897 Zabbix Agent stopped. Zabbix 3.0.0 (revision 58455).
```

PSK File :

```
852db2dca368484050c9b15810e3453f49cc8086b8dd2b04a1 1af4de3f74c42f
```

When try to start zabbix_agent service receive :

[image]

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: You seem to have two numbers in a PSK file - there should only be one.

Answer (score 0):

The default Zabbix Windows agent binaries are compiled without encryption support.

You can vote on a feature request to include encryption, and you can also find some builds with encryption attached to https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-3047 .